# reverting a RemoveField migration (django.db.utils.IntegrityError)

Tags: python, django, database, migration

Im trying to revert a migration by migrating to previous migration but i got this error:

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "field_name" contains null values`

this problem occurs when a `migrations.RemoveField` is in the migration which is reverted to. when the migration is reverting a field by `null=False` is created.
How can i resolve the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Revert Django 1.7 RemoveField migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878428/revert-django-1-7-removefield-migration)